# Loading large amount of binary data into RAM

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, vector

My application needs to load from MegaBytes to dozens of GigaBytes of binary data (multiple files) into RAM. After some search, I decided to use `std::vector<unsigned char>` for this purpose, although I am not sure it's the best choice.

I would use one vector for each file. As application previously knows file size, it would call `reserve()` to allocate memory for it. Sometimes the application might need to fully read a file and in some others only part of it and vector's iterators are nice for that. It may need to unload a file from RAM and put other in place, `std::vector::swap()` and `std::vector::shrink_to_fit()` would be very useful. I don't want to have the hard work of dealing with low level memory allocation stuff (otherwise would go with C).

I've some questions:

- Application must load the more files from a list it can into RAM. How would it know if there is enough memory space to load one more file? Should it call `reserve()` and look for errors? How? Reference only says `reserve()` throws an exception when requested size is greater than `std::vector::max_size`.
- Is `std::vector<unsigned char>` applicable for getting such large amount of binary data into RAM? I'm worried about `std::vector::max_size`, since its reference says its value would depend on system or implementation limitations. I presume system limitation is free RAM, is it right? So, no problem. But what about implementations limitation? Are there anything regarding to implementations that could prevent me from doing what I want to? Case affirmative, please give me an alternative.
- And what if I want to use entire RAM space, except N GigaBytes? Is the best way really to use `sysinfo()` and deduce based on free RAM if it is possible to load each file?

Obs.: This section of the application must be get the more performance (low processing time/CPU usage and RAM consumption) possible. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: I'd suggest investigate using memory mapped files - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: *Very* few systems have hundreds of gigabytes of RAM.  You can (probably) read that much into a vector, but (most of) it will be stored in the swap file.

Comment: ... and on top of that, even less systems really have a requirement to keep these gigabytes in RAM.

Comment: Have a look at Boost.Iostreams (mapped_file) and/or Boost.Interprocess.

Comment: @MartinBonner my application is intended to run on servers having from 8GB to 128GB or more of RAM (the more, the best, depends on customer's needs). Other applications of same type also makes extensive use of RAM. It's needed for greater performance.

Comment: Obs.: despite what I said, most of files loaded into RAM will likely be less than 1GB, but it may also happen to need to load much larger files there and my application must be ready for that.

Comment: Even with 128G, you won't load "hundreds" - but I concur with the other suggestion that `mmap` is the way to go.  If you want to port to Windows, boost has libraries for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How would it know if there is enough memory space to load one more file?

You wouldn't know before hand. Wrap the loading process in try - catch. If memory runs out, then a `std::bad_alloc` will be thrown (assuming you use default allocators). Assume that memory is sufficient in the loading code, and deal with the lack of memory in the exception handler.

> But what about implementations limitation?
>   ...
>   Are there anything regarding to implementations that could prevent me from doing what I want to?

You can check `std::vector::max_size` at run time to verify.

If the program is compiled with a 64 bit word size, then it is quite likely that the vector has sufficient max_size for a few hundred gigabytes.

---

> This section of the application must be get the more performance

This conflicts with

> I don't want to have the hard work of dealing with low level memory allocation stuff

But in case low level memory stuff is worth it for the performance, you could [memory-map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) the file into memory.

---

> I've read on some SO questions to avoid them on applications that need high performance and prefer dealing with return values, errno, etc

Unfortunately for you, non-throwing memory allocation is not an option if you use the standard containers. If you are allergic to exceptions, then you must use another implementation of a vector - or whatever container you decide to use. You don't need any container with mmap, though.

> Won't handling exceptions break performance?

Luckily for you, run time cost of exceptions is insignificant compared to reading hundreds of gigabytes from disk.

> May it be better to run sysinfo() and work on checking free RAM before loading a file?

`sysinfo` call may very well be slower than handling an exception (I haven't measured, that is just a conjecture) - and it won't tell you about process specific limits that may exist.

> And also, it looks hard and costly to repetitively try load a file, catch exception and try load a smaller file (requires recursion?)

No recursion needed. You can use it if you prefer; it can be written with tail call, that can be optimized away.

---

> About memory mapping: I took a look on it sometime ago and found boring to deal with. Would require to use C's open() and all that stuff and say bye to std::fstream.

Once you have mapped the memory, it is easier to use than `std::fstream`. You can skip the copying into vector part, and simply use the mapped memory as if it was an array that already exists in memory.

> Looks like best way of partially reading a file using std::fstream is to derive std::streambuf

I don't see why you would need to derive anything. Just use `std::basic_fstream::seekg()` to skip to the part that you wish to read.

Comment: Won't handling exceptions break performance? I've read on some SO questions to avoid them on applications that need high performance and prefer dealing with return values, `errno`, etc, because of side-table stored in RAM's slow _cold_ zone when exception is thrown, or something like that. May it be better to run `sysinfo()` and work on checking free RAM before loading a file? That would avoid using exceptions and give me more flexibility to control RAM usage. And also, it looks hard and costly to repetitively try load a file, catch exception and try load a smaller file (requires recursion?).

Comment: About memory mapping: I took a look on it sometime ago and found boring to deal with. Would require to use C's `open()` and all that stuff and say bye to `std::fstream`. Looks like best way of partially reading a file using `std::fstream` is to derive `std::streambuf` and implement a "range buffer", argh. `std::vector<unsigned char>` makes all so easy...

Comment: @Tiago.SR I've extended my answer to answer your new questions.

Comment: Hm, ok. Maybe I consider `mmap` for a future improvement, as it will take much time to implement everything. Now I want to get things working as soon as possible with a decent performance, so relying on `vector` and `deque` looks nice. I think it would be needed to try `reserve()` and if exception is thrown, catch it and try `reserve()` for a smaller file repetitively until I get no exception. This may mean a lot of exceptions until some file is successfully loaded, whereas a single `sysinfo` call would be sufficient. But these process specific limits your mentioned might be a problem...

Comment: I read your answers again and now it looks better to use `mmap` since begin, except what for what is said here: http://dannythorpe.com/2004/03/19/the-hidden-costs-of-memory-mapped-files/
Page faults, need for continuous block of address space (`vector` also has same problem, but mixing with `deque` eases it), no control over how long file stays in RAM...

Comment: The memory allocation will only fail when he runs out of **virtual** memory, not RAM.

Comment: @MartinBonner yes, but I won't under any circumstances setup swap in a server for my application, so virtual memory == RAM. Swap + `mmap` seems to be disastrous, as I may be expecting some file to be quickly accessible with RAM speed, but it would come from slow hard disk.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to [@user2097303's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38654242/6610), I want to add that `vector` guarantees contiguous allocation.  For long running applications, this will result in memory fragmentation, and in the end, no contiguous block of memory will be present anymore, although between blocks, plenty of space is free.

Therefore it may be a good idea to store your data into [`deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)

Comment: Won't `deque` be slower because of the need to access different parts of RAM to get the full file? Maybe I could use `vector` to load initial files into RAM, and them use `deque` if needed to replace or add new ones... what do you think?